# Как активировать режим лайв в PayPal?

Tags: android, paypal

Есть мобильное приложение которое будет использовать PayPal sdk для оплаты услуг. В бизнес аккаунте paypal создано приложение и ключ работает в режиме тестирования но ключ во вкладке Live не работает. Если кто-нибудь сталкивался с этой проблемой опишите как вы ее решили?

Comment: Почитай [тут](https://habrahabr.ru/post/207446/).

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что следует адресовать его в техподдержку